# Extracting from regexp_extract()

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to remove 'E' character from the timestamp(in the rows where it is present) but the above query return the timestamp without the hours.
Note: 'E' may or may not be present in all the timestamp rows.

Query: select 
regexp_extract(time_stamp,’(E?)(.*)’,2) as time_stamp
from X 
where ((time_stamp >= 'E00:00:00.00' and time_stamp <= 'E23:59:59.00') or (time_stamp >= '00:00:00.00' and time_stamp <= '23:59:59.00')) LIMIT 15).

Please suggest the required changes.

Comment: Can you share some sample data for which you are observing this issue, and also which version of Hive you are running?

Answer (score 0):

If you are stripping out a constant string the TRANSLATE built-in function might be clearer. For example:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(time_stamp, 'E', '') AS time_stamp FROM X;
```